# Adress of adress weirdness (beginner question)

Tags: c, cmake, c99

I'm tiring to understand what occurs when you printf an array. If I understood correctly, `numbers` should point to the first element of the array. `printf("Float:%f \n", (*numbers));` prints `13.6` as expected. I thought I could print the address by omitting the asterisk.

```
int main(){
    float numbers[5] = {13.6, 2.78, 3.42, 4, 5};

    printf("Int:%n \n", (numbers));
    printf("Float:%f \n", (numbers));
}
```

Output:

```
Int:Float:-1.#QNAN0
```

So this is the first point of confusion. **Why can't I just print the address as an Integer?**

Now, what really surprised me was this:

```
int main(){
    float numbers[5] = {13.6, 2.78, 3.42, 4, 5};

    printf("content: %f\n", numbers[2]);

    printf("Int:%n \n", (numbers));
    printf("Float:%f \n", (numbers));
}
```

Output:

```
content: 3.420000
Int:Float:3.420000
```

What? **How does printing `numbers[3]` affect the value of numbers?** This works for all `numbers[n]`, not just `2`.

I just started learning C and I'd really appreciate some guidance here (let me know if I can improve mi question too). Thank you in advance!

Comment: Read up on the meaning of `"%n"`  and e.g. `"%p"`. I think you missed something there.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that.

Comment: 2 UBs in three lines ...

Comment: @P__J__ What's a UBs?

Comment: UB = *undefined behavior* . It means the code is performing some action whose behavior is not formally defined by the language standard. It should be avoided, and ideally non-existent, in your code. Without behavioral definition, chaos is the result. Part of avoiding it by understanding the functions you're calling, knowing *exactly* what they're expecting for arguments, and staying in that lane.

Comment: Indeed first thing learning C is **check the manual twice, or three times** for the correct operation, arguments, etc, and compile **always** with `-Wall -Werror -pedantic` (or similar, since I believe you're using a Windows system due to how ugly the NaN printing looks like)

Comment: I guess everyone has a first encounter with undefined behavior. Thank you all for the tips @AnttiHaapala

Comment: Note that there are still 3 levels of undefined behaviour: undefined behaviour that you can get past by the current compiler you're using and it is stably producing the same behaviour you'd expect, undefined behaviour by C standard but explicitly documented by the compiler, and undefined behaviour that really does wild things in your implementation. This falls to the last category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So this is the first point of confusion. Why can't I just print the address as an Integer?

You can, but you need to use the `%p` format specifier:

```
printf("Memory Address: %p\n", numbers);
```

When you use `%f` you're telling `printf` that `numbers` is a float (which it's not). `numbers` is a pointer to an array of floats (a pointer is a variable that holds a memory address).

`printf` isn't smart and believes you when you tell it that `numbers` is a float so it attempts to print the memory address of `numbers` as a float. The memory address isn't a valid float so it prints `#QNAN0` which means `Not A Number`.

> What? How does printing numbers[3] affect the value of numbers? This works for all numbers[n], not just 2.

When you use the brackets, you're saying "follow the memory address and give me the Nth element". So when you write `numbers[3]` your getting back the 3rd element which is `3.42`.

As to why in your last example `printf("Float:%f \n", (numbers));` is printing the Nth value? Well, `%f` isn't the right format specifier to use so the fact it prints `3.42` is a fluke in `printf`.

I tried your code using the `clang` C compiler and I get `3.42` too but on `cl` (Microsoft's C Compiler) I get `0.0`. You should use the correct format specifier for what you're printing. Don't rely on flukes.

Comment: Perfectly clear, thank you! I'd still love to know what is causing one (valid) printf to influence future operations. I'll go have a look at the compiler's source code and prepare to fail miserably at understanding it.